# RPM package conflict between remi-safe and mariadb repo

Tags: repository, centos7, mariadb-10.5

I am running Centos 7 with additional repositories remi-safe and mariaDB-10.5.
Everything worked fine for several months, now I get a package conflict when running yum update:

```
Error: Package: libzip5-1.8.0-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
Required: libzstd(x86-64) >= 1.3.6
Available: libzstd-1.3.4-1.el7.x86_64 (mariadb-main)
           libzstd(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.el7
Error: Package: libzip5-1.8.0-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
Required: libzstd(x86-64) >= 1.3.6
Install: libzstd-1.3.4-1.el7.x86_64 (mariadb-main)
         libzstd(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.el7
```

I tried to solve this by setting priorities to the yum repos (I gave 1 to MariaDB, 2 to Remi, 3 to Centos Base packages and 4 to EPEL) but this did not solve the issue.

How could I get remi-safe and mariadb-10.5 to live on the system again without quarreling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPEL have zstd 1.5.0, so you must use this one

So should either disable priority plugin or configure it properly, with higher priority for base and EPEL repository, higher priority means lower value.

Notice that mariadb 10.5 is available in official [CentOS SCLo](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/SCLo) repository, which is probably better integrated to system.

Comment: In my understanding I need to give higher priority to more specialised repositories (like Remi). If I give priority to Centos-Base rather than e.g. REMI, I will always stay with the Centos-Base-Version rather than the one served by REMI. I anyway solved this problem by excluding libzstd in mariadb.repo:
`exclude=libzstd*`
The result is the same, the EPEL version of libzstd will be used and both remi-safe and mariadb-repo can use that one.